# Why is this quote of Thomas Edison grammatically correct? "The Value of an Idea Lies in the Using of It"

Tags: grammar

Based on [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/359229/what-s-the-difference-between-the-using-of-this-machine-and-using-my-neighbou) it's not?! What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: Which version bothers you? I don't know or care *exactly* how Edison originally phrased it, but I'd guess the version in your actual title *(the value lies in **using** it)* is the most acceptable today - so that's probably what people would tend to repeat, regardless of "historical accuracy". That's of your *two* versions. But I at least would probably use *the value lies in **the use** of it* myself. Personally I'm not convinced *any* are "ungrammatical" - but I think the plain noun ***use*** (almost *always* with article) is more idiomatic for the context than the gerund ***using*** .

Comment: @FumbleFingers I have edited the question. It's the "The" that is bothering me.

Comment: While you were responding, I was just editing my comment re the article. I don't believe there's any meaningful "syntactic principle"  either requiring OR forbidding the article, with either ***use*** or ***using***, so if any answers or comments on the rearlier question suggest anything like that, I completely disagree with them. All we've got here is a matter of *idiomacy*. I know which one of the four permutations (use/using, with/without article) I prefer, and I'm pretty sure that I could prove using NGrams that most people agree with me. But it's about "idiomacy", not "grammar"

Comment: Regarding just the article, and forgetting about the possible use of a gerund, there's a syntactically identical example that's vastly more common than Edison's aphorism: *The proof of the pudding lies in [**the**] eating [[of] it]*. If you check that out in Google Books, you'll find that both versions are perfectly common (but the one *with* the article is significantly *more* common).

Comment: ...where main alternatives there are *...lies in **the eating**, ...lies in **the eating of it,*** and *...lies in **eating it.***  You'll rarely encounter *...lies in **eating of it***, but I can't really explain why that is.

Comment: "Nothing in his life | Became him like **the leaving it**" - as [Malcolm](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/macbeth/macbeth.1.4.html) says of little-known Thane of Cawdor, Macdonwald.

Comment: It's possible to search Google Books for things like [**"pudding lies in the eating" -"in the eating of it"**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22pudding+lies+in+the+eating%22+-%22in+the+eating+of+it%22), to largely restrict results to those instances where "eating" is the last word in the sentence/clause. So on a whim I just searched for [**"pudding lies in eating" -"in eating it"**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22pudding+lies+in+eating%22+-%22in+eating+it%22) with no articles OR **[of] it** pronoun. At first glance, most of the writers there have *Indian* names.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian: I've no idea whether Shakespeare himself included the article when he wrote that example, but there are [many written instances](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Nothing+in+his+life+Became+him+like+leaving+it%22) of it *without* the article. That kind of "slightly inaccurate quoting" often happens when a lot of people aren't really happy with the grammar of some "original" text, so (deliberately or otherwise) they make slight changes - which then get repeated and gain traction despite howls of dismay from those scholars who like to check their sources! :)

Comment: I recall that a couple of decades ago UK politicians suddenly became enamoured of discarding the article in the sequence ***not fit for purpose***. At first I didn't like it one little bit (I expected *not fit for **the** purpose* - or some other "determiner", such as possessive ***its***), but [this chart shows how common the usage now is,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=not+fit+for+purpose%2Cnot+fit+for+the+purpose&year_start=1960&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) and I've gotten so used to it I now find it entirely natural myself.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Yes. Lots of examples of both. I expect the Macbeth one (which I'd remembered as Antony and Cleopatra!) is accurate though: "of it" spoils the scansion: "Became him like the leaving it; he died | As one that had been studied in his death." I'm with you on _"fit for purpose"_. Thatcher, or someone in her cabinet started it I think.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I'm still fighting a rearguard action against "...asked how difficult **of** a decision it was..." and "laying waste **to** huge swathes of the country..." Maybe dictionaries shouldn't quite keep up! Already the pronunciation of "**dissect**" is shown as /dʌɪˈsɛkt,dɪˈsɛkt/ I sometimes feel a bit sorry for learners hereabouts who just want to know which one is **correct!** :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: The shorter the better! **"The proof of the pudding's in the eating"** or **"(The) proof of the pudding, eh?"**

Comment: @OldBrixtonian: Perhaps we're just showing our age! Language *does* change, and unless we become senile first, at some point we get old enough to notice the change *within our own lifetimes*. When we were younger, all we knew was that older speakers and texts didn't necessarily reflect [our] *current* usage, but now it's often ***I** used to say this, but now I say that*.

Comment: btw - it was [John Reid under Tony Blair](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/av/uk-politics-15786213), long after Thatcher.